# How to show that $\varphi(x, y) = (f(x) + y^2, y^3)$ is injective?

Tags: real-analysis

I need some support. Let be $D, E \subset \mathbb{R}$ two intervals and let be $f : D \to E $ a differentiable, bijective function with $f' \neq 0$. We have no further information concerning $f$.

The goal is to show that  $\varphi(x, y) = (f(x) + y^2, y^3)$ is injective.

I know how to prove that a two-dimensional function is injective. Let us consider another function, for instance $$f(x, y) = (4x - 3y, 2x + y)$$

Suppose $f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_2, y_2)$. I want to show that $(x_1, y_1) = (x_2, y_2)$. The equation $f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_2, y_2)$ means $$ (4x_1 - 3y_1, 2x_1 + y_1) = (4x_2 - 3y_2, 2x_2 + y_2) $$

Equate corresponding components: $$ 4x_1 - 3y_1 = 4x_2 - 3y_2; \quad 2x_1 + y_1 = 2x_2 + y_2 $$

Rewrite the equations: $$ 4(x_1 - x_2) = 3(y_1 - y_2), \quad 2(x_1 - x_2) = -(y_1 - y_2) $$ The second of these equations gives $ y_1 - y_2 = -2(x_1 - x_2).$ Substitute this into the first equation: $$ 4(x_1 - x_2) = -6(x_1 - x_2) \implies 10(x_1 - x_2) = 0 \implies x_1 - x_2 = 0 \implies x_1 = x_2 $$ Plugging this into $y_1 - y_2 = -2(x_1 - x_2)$ gives $y_1 - y_2 = 0$, so $y_1 = y_2$.  Therefore, $(x_1, y_1) = (x_2, y_2) $, and $f$ is injective. So far, so good.

Now we consider $\varphi(x, y) = (f(x) + y^2, y^3)$ again. Can I rewrite it in $\varphi(x, y) = (y^2, y^3)$ and ignore $f(x)$ because we already know that $f$ is bijective and therefore injective?

Comment: I don't see how exactly is this proved. That is, exactly why the injectivity of $(y^2,y^3)$ implies the injectivity of $(f(x)+y^2,y^3)$?

Comment: It was a question, not a claim! Can I ignore $f(x)$ in $((f(x) + y^2, y^3)$ because we already know $f$ is injective?

Comment: Please note that the function $\varphi(y) = (y^2,y^3)$ is not injective. Look up the Inverse function theorem (of course one doesnt need that, but its illustrative). Your function has a nonzero Jacobian determinant everywhere while the Jacobian of $y \mapsto (y^2,y^3)$ vanishes at $0$.

Comment: Sry what I wrote above is not correct. The function $\varphi(y) = (y^2,y^3)$ is injective. And the composition of injective functions is injective, so your way works. You could look up the Inverse function theorem (of course one doesnt need that, but its illustrative). Your function has a nonzero Jacobian determinant everywhere, so this even shows that your function is invertible with continuous differentiable inverse, while the Jacobian of $y \mapsto (y^2,y^3)$ vanishes at $0$, so this function would not have a local continous differentiable inverse at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just apply what you did above; i.e. a map $f:A\rightarrow B$ is injective if $$f(a_1)=f(a_2)\Rightarrow a_1=a_2.$$

Just apply this with $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $a_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $a_2=(x_2,y_2)$.

Assuming $\varphi(x_1,y_1)=\varphi(x_2,y_2)$ yields

$$f(x_1)+y_1^2=f(x_2)+y_2^2,\text{ and}$$
$$y_1^3=y_2^3.$$

We know that $x\mapsto x^3$ is injective on the reals so this gives us $y_1=y_2$ so that

$$f(x_1)+y_1^2=f(x_2)+y_1^2\Rightarrow f(x_1)=f(x_2)\Rightarrow x_1=x_2$$

also because $f$ is injective... i.e. $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$ and so $\varphi$ is injective.